# Spring Boot : Apache CXF SOAP with @RestController

Tags: soap, spring-boot, cxf, spring-restcontroller

I am making Spring Boot rest service using @RestController, in same project I am also exposing the Apache CXF SOAP service like

**@RestController Code**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/mobileTopUpService")
public class TopUpRestService {

@RequestMapping(value="/processTopUpRequest", method=RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

    public ResponseEntity<TopUpRequestDTO> processTopUpRequest(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, @Valid RequestEntity<TopUpRequestDTO> _requestEntity) {


        return new ResponseEntity<>(new exampleDTO("hi"), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

**Apache CXF SOAP**

```
    @Configuration
    @Import(ApplicationConfiguration.class)
    public class WebServiceConfig
    {
        public static final String SERVLET_MAPPING_URL_PATH = "/*";
        public static final String SERVICE_NAME_URL_PATH = "/services";

        @Autowired
        private ApplicationConfiguration applicationConfiguration;

        @Bean
        public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet()
        {
            return new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), SERVLET_MAPPING_URL_PATH);
        }

        @Bean(name = Bus.DEFAULT_BUS_ID)
        public SpringBus springBus()
        {
            return new SpringBus();
        }

        @Bean
        public ERSBackendService ersBackendServiceImpl()
        {
            return new ERSBackendServiceImpl();
        }

        @Bean
        public Endpoint endpoint()
        {
            EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), ersBackendServiceImpl());
            endpoint.publish(SERVICE_NAME_URL_PATH);

            AutomaticWorkQueue executorQueue = createThreadPoolExecutorQueue();
            endpoint.setExecutor(executorQueue);

            return endpoint;
        }
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory()
{
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory("/backend-service", Integer.valueOf(applicationConfiguration.getPort()));
    return factory;
}
}
```

SOAP Service are running fine after change but REST (@RestController) stop working, but if I disables the methods

```
//  @Bean
//  public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServlet()
//  {
//      return new ServletRegistrationBean(new CXFServlet(), SERVLET_MAPPING_URL_PATH);
//  }
```

and

```
    @Bean
//  public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory()
//  {
//      TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory("/backend-service", Integer.valueOf("8007"));
//      return factory;
//  }
//}
```

and run 
http://localhost:8007/mobileTopUpService/processTopUpRequest/
the @RestController runs fine but not soap.

I need to run both @RestController and CXF SOAP, kindly suggest.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it as @EnableWebMvc in class where starting boot app
i.e SpringApplication.run(ApplicationStartup.class, args);

Moved ServletRegistrationBean in spring boot class too,

disbaled method
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory() {...}

Answer (score 2):

I've just working with SOAP and REST servicies together. Here's my configuration: *(At the end of the answer, I included a sample project)*

**application.properties**

```
cxf.path=/services
cxf.servlet.load-on-startup=-1
```

**WebServiceConfig**

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
public class WebServiceConfig {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WsEndpointsConfiguration.class);


    @Autowired
    private Bus bus;


    @Value("${cxf.path}")
    private String cxfServletPath;


    @Autowired
    private YourServiceInterface yourService;


    public Logger getLOGGER() {
        return LOGGER;
    }


    public Bus getBus() {
        return bus;
    }


    public String getCxfServletPath() {
        return cxfServletPath;
    }


    public void setCxfServletPath(String cxfServletPath) {
        this.cxfServletPath = cxfServletPath;
    }


    public YourServiceInterface getYourServiceInterface() {
        return yourService;
    }


    @Bean
    public Endpoint yourWebServiceEndpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(getBus(), new YourWebServiceEndpoint(getYourServiceInterface()));
        endpoint.publish("/YourWebService");
        return endpoint;
    }


    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean openEntityManagerInViewFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean filterRegBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        filterRegBean.setFilter(new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter());
        List<String> urlPatterns = new ArrayList<String>();
        urlPatterns.add(getCxfServletPath() + "/*");
        filterRegBean.setUrlPatterns(urlPatterns);
        if (getLOGGER().isDebugEnabled()) {
            getLOGGER().debug("Registering the 'OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter' filter for the '"
                .concat(getCxfServletPath() + "/*").concat("' URL."));
        }
        return filterRegBean;
    }
}
```

Replace the `@Autowired` service with your own service interface.

You could check a full example here:

https://github.com/jcagarcia/proofs/tree/master/spring-security-and-formatters

Related classes from the sample provided above:

- [Configuration class](https://github.com/jcagarcia/proofs/blob/master/spring-security-and-formatters/src/main/java/org/springframework/roo/petclinic/config/WsEndpointsConfiguration.java)
- [WebService API](https://github.com/jcagarcia/proofs/blob/master/spring-security-and-formatters/src/main/java/org/springframework/roo/petclinic/ws/api/OwnerWebService.java)
- [WebService Implementation](https://github.com/jcagarcia/proofs/blob/master/spring-security-and-formatters/src/main/java/org/springframework/roo/petclinic/ws/endpoint/OwnerWebServiceEndpoint.java)
- [application.properties](https://github.com/jcagarcia/proofs/blob/master/spring-security-and-formatters/src/main/resources/application.properties#L3)

Hope it helps,